# What is the best way to set indexes in MySQL database tables with SailsJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

[Waterline supports indexing out of the box](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline#indexing), unfortunately not for any adapter.

[sails-mysql](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql) adapter doesn't seem to support it.

For example, following field in a model, will make an error:

```
user: { 
  model: 'user',
  index: true
}
```

> Error: The attribute `user` on the `topic` model contains invalid properties. The property `index` isn't a recognized property.

The question is, if adapter is not supporting indexing, what is the best way to do that in SailsJS?

I'm using:

```
{
  "sails": "^1.0.0-27",
  "sails-mysql": "^1.0.0-7",
  "waterline": "v0.13.0-rc4"
}
```

Comment: How are you creating tables in your database? Using sails migration or SQL or something else?

Comment: Using waterline's schema. I found a problem already, and made a PR https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-schema/pull/80

Answer (score 6):

After reverse engineering of `sails-mysql`, `waterline-schema` and `waterline` modules, I found undocumented possibility to set indexes inside `autoMigrations` property. Like following:

```
foo: { 
  type: 'number'
  autoMigrations: { index: true }
}
```

Comment: Interesting find, I personally just drop down to more native approaches when it comes to cases like this. So a service with like a createTable method which creates the table and indexes at the same time using something like mysql@npm.